# Displaying web based visualisation or graphing of data based on a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, graph, data-visualization

I am working on a web application for a client that uses a postgresql database. I want the client to be able to go to a certain area of the site where the data from the database is displayed in graph form (for example, sales figures over a 6 month period). Is there a plugin I could use for this (I don't have any experience of this, so an easy one, or one with tutorials available would be great). I had a look at BIRT, which says it has a web based option but I couldn't really figure it out. I don't want the client to have to download and go through another program, I just want them to go to a url within their site, and it's all just presented to them there and then.

Any sort of pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`HighCharts`, at http://www.highcharts.com/, works well for this case -- I use it fairly often. It supports `Ajax` data feeds in `JSON` format, so you can write an `endpoint` which returns the `JSON` representing the data from `Postgres` and which gets called from a `JavaScript` function which creates the graphs using that data (you would place that call in a `ready` function).

Also, if you're using `Postgres 9.3` or higher, it supports `JSON` natively, so you can do the JSON conversion in the `SQL` query itself, as opposed to post-processing the results in your `Python` or other backend code.

`Highcharts` is reasonably flexible and allows for a variety of nice-looking, functional charts and graphs. If you want to get much fanicer, `d3` may be worth a look. These are some the types of graphs/charts it can do: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

I have not used `d3` myself, however.

For the scenario you described above, `Highcharts` seems like it would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, and a lot has happened since 2016. There is now ChartJS as well - http://chartjs.org/, for example, which is easier to use than HighCharts and very flexible (I've used both).

What they both don't do is dynamic data. If you want that your client decides which data he wants to watch - that part you need to write yourself.